# If $f$ is bounded and continuous, is $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(x+z)-f(x)}{|z|}dz$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f$ is bounded and continuous, is it true that $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(x+z)-f(x)}{|z|}dz$$ is bounded? If not, what's the weakest assumption on $f$ that makes the result hold true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x):=\tanh^2 x$, and call your integral $g(x)$. Then
$$g(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\tanh^2 z\over|z|}\>dz=\infty\ ,$$
since $\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}\tanh z=1$.

Comment: In fact, $\displaystyle \int_0^x \dfrac{\tanh^2 z}{|z|} \ \mathrm dz \approx \ln x$

Comment: What assumptions should we have on $f$ to make the result hold true?

Comment: Using the same argument, a necessary condition on $f$ is that $$g(0)=\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{|z|} \mathrm{d}z$$ is finite. In particular this implies $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = f(0)$. Maybe this condition is sufficient too?

Comment: @Crostul Wouldn't we also need this to hold for arbitrary $x$?